# Trying to select database based on server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerA')
begin
    use DatabaseA
    select top 5 * from dbo.SignUPRequest
end
else if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerB')
begin
    use DatabaseB
    select top 5 * from dbo.SignUPRequest
end
```

When I run this on ServerA, I get a message that DatabaseB doesn't exist on ServerA, which it doesnt, but I don't understand why it's trying to read if the second if evaluates to false.

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Database 'DatabaseB' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: Both queries are for the same table -- why does it matter which database?  For this to work, we have to assume the user account has access to the other database, and that the database is on the same server...

Comment: Yea - unfortunately we have different database names depending on which server you're on.  And because I'm often switching between environments, I'm often having to change the database (the select statements are usually more complicated, this is just an example).

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx) for how to identify tables in other databases and on other servers using four part names.  You don't need dynamic SQL or a `use` statement and can query across multiple sources in a single statement, e.g. `JOIN` table from two databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is parsed before it is run. When it is parsed SQL Server checks that it can access everything in the code, it cannot access the database that exists on the other server so the parsing step of running the code fails. As a result, you get the error message you've shown.

If you want to get around that you can put the code in the IF blocks as dynamically executed code (I always feel this is a bit of a hack/workaround).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerA')
begin
    SET @sql = 'use DatabaseA; select top 5 * from dbo.SignUPRequest;'
end
else if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerB')
begin
    SET @sql = 'use DatabaseB; select top 5 * from dbo.SignUPRequest'
end

EXEC (@sql)
```

So, what happens here is that you defer the parsing & running of the code that uses the appropriate database for the server to run time, as that what the EXEC statement at the end does.

**UPDATE**

Based on the additional comment below you could also rewrite this as:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerA')
begin
    select top 5 * from DatabaseA.dbo.SignUPRequest;
end
else if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerB')
begin
    select top 5 * from DatabaseB.dbo.SignUPRequest;
end
```

So, instead of putting in a `USE <database-name>` at the start, you can also more fully qualify the name of the table in your select statement. If you only have one line of SQL to deal with this could be more effective.

Comment: Great thanks--this will do it, and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Hmm... The problem with the above is I'd have to repeat the statement(s) I want to run, or if I add to @sql outside of the if sections, I just get back 'Command(s) completed successfully.' instead of the results.

Comment: The "use" statement is now scoped within the EXEC so you revert back to what ever database you were in when you started when the EXEC completes. Incidentally, you were repeating the statements anyway, although not quite, because if you think about it within the scope of the database you're using they are referring to completely separate tables, and therefore not really the same statement (they just look the same because the scope they are executed in provides additional context to the parser)

Comment: I've added an alternative solution.

Comment: A `SELECT`/`INTO` would allow capturing data from the appropriate database into a temporary table for further processing by common code.  That may be simpler than have a large quantity of replicated code.  It would depend on the quantity of data, frequency of execution, ... .  I would also suggest changing `@@servername` to `@@databasename` to more accurately reflect its usage.  "This comment adds something useful to the post."(sm)

Answer (score 1):

You get the error when the query is compiled, not on execution. You can execute the statements with `exec` to get them in a batch that compiles only if the database exists.

```
if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerA')
begin
   exec(N'use DatabaseA
          select top 5 * from dbo.SignUPRequest')
end
else if ((select @@servername) = 'ServerB')
begin
   exec(N'use DatabaseB
          select top 5 * from dbo.SignUPRequest')
end
```